# FIFO file in TCL

Tags: tcl, freeze, fifo, mkfifo, gunzip

I need to unzip file in a named pipe return it:

```
proc unzip_file_if_needed { fileName } {
    if { [file extension $fileName] != ".gz" } {
        return $fileName;
    }
    set tmpDir [fileutil::tempdir]
    set tmpFileName [ file join $tmpDir [ pid ] ]
    if { [file exists $tmpFileName ] } {
        file delete $tmpFileName
    }
    exec mkfifo $tmpFileName
    exec gunzip -c $fileName > $tmpFileName &
    return $tmpFileName
}
```

It hangs on 
`exec gunzip -c $fileName > $tmpFileName &`

Comment: According to [mkfifo manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo), such file needs to be open simultaneously for reading and writing. It means that someone needs to read the data which you unzip into it. Does someone read what you unzip into mkfifo file?

Comment: Yes, it will be read after function call, that's why gunzip executed in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue in this way :

```
proc unzip_file_if_needed { fileName } {
    if { [file extension $fileName] != ".gz" } {
        return $fileName;
    }
    set tmpDir [fileutil::tempdir]
    set pId [pid]
    set tmpFileName [ file join $tmpDir pId ]
    set unzipCmd [ file join $tmpDir [ append pId "cmd.sh" ] ]
    if { [file exists $tmpFileName ] } {
        file delete $tmpFileName
    }

    if { [file exists $unzipCmd ] } {
        file delete $unzipCmd
    }

    set cmdDesc [open $unzipCmd { CREAT EXCL RDWR} 0777]
    puts $cmdDesc "\#!\/bin\/bash\n gunzip -c \$1 > \$2"
    close $cmdDesc

    exec mkfifo $tmpFileName
    exec $unzipCmd $fileName $tmpFileName >&@1 &

    return $tmpFileName
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the kernel will block in the `open()` system call until the fifo is opened for the opposite direction, and Tcl creates the redirections in the parent process prior to forking (because this allows for much more reliable error handling in normal circumstances). What you *need* is to get the `O_NONBLOCK` flag passed into the `open()` syscall, but the `exec` command doesn't give you control over that. So some trickery is required!

```
set fd [open $tmpFileName {WRONLY NONBLOCK}]
exec gunzip -c $fileName >@$fd &
close $fd
```

This works by doing the `open` by hand with the flags we want (Tcl maps them in without the `O_` prefix) and then passing that descriptor to the subprocess. Note that since this is the write side of the pipe that we're setting up, we have to open in `WRONLY` mode (which is sort of what `open … w` would do under the covers, minus some flags that don't apply here, and plus the `NONBLOCK` which is the magic we want).

Comment: [Donal Fellows](http://stackoverflow.com/users/301832/donal-fellows) It reports an  ERROR: couldn't open "/tmp/52977": no such device or address ?